# How can I get Python to watch a USB port for any device?

Tags: python, windows, usb, pyusb

On a windows OS, how can I get python to detect if anything is plugged in to a specific USB location on the computer. For example "Port_#0002.Hub_#0003"

I've tried pyUSB which worked fine for detecting a specific device, but I couldn't seem to figure out how to just check a specific port/hub location for any kind of device.

Comment: http://bitpim.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/bitpim/trunk/bitpim/src/native/usb/usb.py?revision=4835&view=markup   see the `alldevices` method maybe

Answer (score 0):

What about polling? Create a Python app that enumerates a list of attached USB devices every couple of seconds or so.

Keep a list/dictionary of your initially detected devices, and compare to that to determine what was attached/detached since your last polling iteration.

This isn't the best approach, and enumerating all the devices takes a short while, so not too sure this would be the most CPU efficient method.